# format ugly c# source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting

I found a C# game http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/BattleField.aspx that does what I need to learn. The source code is poorly formatted and hard to follow. I used Visual Studio's format document, but the format is still bad. How do I reformat the source code to make it easer to read?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio's format document should help.

That being said, if you want more elaborate reformatting, you'll need a third party tool.  [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), for example, has the option of reformatting the code, but also of doing code cleanups (where small refactorings are done on the fly to make the code itself nicer).

They provide a temporary free trial - you can see if it works for your case and this project.

Answer (score 0):

That codes requires refactoring and commenting. Visual Studio can help, but this work is not fully-automated as you understand :)